# Spring boot2.x and ehcache3.5 are error based on annotations

Tags: spring-boot, ehcache

```
//jsr107
  @Configuration
  @EnableCaching
  public class EhCacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {
    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        CacheConfiguration<String, String> cacheConfiguration = 
                CacheConfigurationBuilder
                .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(String.class, String.class, ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(10000L))
.withExpiry(ExpiryPolicyBuilder.timeToIdleExpiration(Duration.ofDays(2L)))
                    .withDispatcherConcurrency(4)
                .build();
        Map<String, org.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration<?, ?>> cacheMap = new HashMap<>();
        cacheMap.put("vsk", cacheConfiguration);
        EhcacheCachingProvider ehcacheCachingProvider = (EhcacheCachingProvider) Caching.getCachingProvider();
         DefaultConfiguration defaultConfiguration = 
                 new DefaultConfiguration(cacheMap, ehcacheCachingProvider.getDefaultClassLoader());
         javax.cache.CacheManager cacheManager = 
                 ehcacheCachingProvider.getCacheManager(ehcacheCachingProvider.getDefaultURI(), defaultConfiguration);
//This is a mistake here.
        return new JCacheCacheManager(cacheManager);
    }
  //SimpleCacheResolver
    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheResolver cacheResolver() {
        return new SimpleCacheResolver();
    }
  //SimpleKeyGenerator
    @Bean
    @Override
    public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
        return new SimpleKeyGenerator();
    }
  //SimpleCacheErrorHandler
    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return new SimpleCacheErrorHandler();
    }
  }
```

Below is an error message.:

```
       **Caused by: javax.cache.CacheException: Multiple CachingProviders have been configured when only a single CachingProvider is expected
        at javax.cache.Caching$CachingProviderRegistry.getCachingProvider(Caching.java:386)**
How do I deal with it?I have tried many changes or not.
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @clevertension is correct. You have more than one caching provider in your classpath.

However, in general this is not normal. So you should clean your classpath to remove everything you don't want.

Then, `Caching` is registering all providers. It is normal so it's not really pretty to remove the others. You can retrieve the one you need with `EhcacheCachingProvider ehcacheCachingProvider = (EhcacheCachingProvider) Caching.getCachingProvider(EhcacheCachingProvider.class.getName());`

Finally, you probably do not need all this code. The following code should do the exact same thing since Spring will look for a registered `CacheManager` to use when enabling caching.

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class EhCacheConfig {

  @Bean
  public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    CacheConfiguration<String, String> cacheConfiguration =
        CacheConfigurationBuilder
            .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(String.class, String.class, ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(10000L))
            .withExpiry(ExpiryPolicyBuilder.timeToIdleExpiration(Duration.ofDays(2L)))
            .withDispatcherConcurrency(4)
            .build();
    Map<String, CacheConfiguration<?, ?>> cacheMap = new HashMap<>();
    cacheMap.put("vsk", cacheConfiguration);
    EhcacheCachingProvider ehcacheCachingProvider = (EhcacheCachingProvider) Caching.getCachingProvider(EhcacheCachingProvider.class.getName());
    DefaultConfiguration defaultConfiguration =
        new DefaultConfiguration(cacheMap, ehcacheCachingProvider.getDefaultClassLoader());
    javax.cache.CacheManager cacheManager =
        ehcacheCachingProvider.getCacheManager(ehcacheCachingProvider.getDefaultURI(), defaultConfiguration);
    return new JCacheCacheManager(cacheManager);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

the exception message is clear that you have multiple cache providers, so if you want to know all the cache provider, you can add the following code snippet in your spring-boot main function

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //list all the caching provider
        Iterator<CachingProvider> iterator = Caching.getCachingProviders(Caching.getDefaultClassLoader()).iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            CachingProvider provider = iterator.next();
            if (!(provider instanceof EhcacheCachingProvider)) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }

        SpringApplication.run(Run.class, args);
    }
```

Comment: hi,
The output of the program is as follows:

cache:org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider@70b0b186
cache:org.redisson.jcache.JCachingProvider@ba8d91c
cache:org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider@463d23f5
cache:org.redisson.jcache.JCachingProvider@7cfb2a5a

I didn't find it in the program. How can I solve it, please?

Comment: i give you a workaround of this issue, the code is updated

Comment: Is it because my bag has been misled?

Comment: if the cache provider is not ehcache, we need to **iterator.remove();**

Comment: if (StringUtils.contains(iterator.next().toString(), "EhcacheCachingProvider")) {
          iterator.remove();
   }

When I remove a Provider, the error message is different.
ClassCastException: org. redisson. jcache. JCachingProvider cannot be cast to org. ehcache. jsr107. EhcacheCaching Provider
This other framework depends on something.

Comment: CachingProvider provider = iterator.next();
            if (!(provider instanceof EhcacheCachingProvider)) {
                iterator.remove();
            }

Comment: It's still wrong, but the wrong message is as follows:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CacheManager is required

Comment: change your code from **return new SimpleCacheResolver();** to  **return new SimpleCacheResolver(cacheManager());**

Comment: It's still wrong, 
I found a conflict with this jar, redisson-3.6.5.jar, and I found a conflict with this jar, redisson-3.6.5.jar has the following code:
Public class JCachingProvider implements CachingProvider.

Comment: we have already remove the cache provider that is not the EhcacheCachingProvider, can you give a gist url to show the latest version of your code?

Comment: where is the code of your spring boot Application that have a main method there?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the multiple CachingProvider:

```
    Iterable<CachingProvider> iterable = Caching.getCachingProviders();
    iterable.forEach(cachingProvider -> {
        System.out.println("cachingProvider=" + cachingProvider);
    });
```

change Caching.getCachingProvider() to use the specific one:
e.g:

```
    Caching.getCachingProvider("org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to tell spring which CachingProvider to use by setting the
`spring.cache.jcache.provider` property like

```
spring.cache.jcache.provider=org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider
```

I discovered this by reviewing the implementation of the `JCacheCacheConfiguration` which Spring uses to provide the CacheManager Bean. It uses `cacheProperties.getJcache().getProvider()` to determine which CacheProvider to use. If it is not specified, then it assumes there is only one provider.

From CacheProperties.JCache:

```
    /**
     * Fully qualified name of the CachingProvider implementation to use to retrieve
     * the JSR-107 compliant cache manager. Needed only if more than one JSR-107
     * implementation is available on the classpath.
     */
    private String provider;
```